# Python versions mess not able to successfully install packages anymore

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I am using Python version 3.11 with MacOS Ventura 13.1 (M1 chip) and cannot successfully install packages anymote. Upon installing them (apparently successfully) Python does not find them and is thus also not able to uninstall them.

I have a lot of research related and thus really important packages installed under a folder opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/

How can I get them to work with 3.11?
And a few more questions:
a) For some reason `pip install` doesn't work anymore, `pip3 install` does however, is that normal?
b) whenever I install something it says:

```
[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0
[notice] To update, run: python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip
user@MacBook-user ~ % python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-23.0

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0
[notice] To update, run: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

so it kind of shows the message on repeat although it says, it has successfully installed pip.

I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall python, but it does not seem to work either.
(I also seem to have some issue with installing specific packages from time to time, which is why I assume something is off, but neither reinstalling nor upgrading has worked)

As per the comment:

`which python3.11` shows `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11` - how can I change my setup so it will work with my previous packages?
`opt/homebrew/opt/python3.11` is an alias for `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.1`

---

**Update:**
since the whole M1 thing seems to be a mess, I un- and reinstalled brew, CommandLine Tools and python

I am running things on python 3.10.9 now, having it freshly installed it still says
`[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0 [notice] To update, run: python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

it now is:
`which python3.10 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10`

(regardless of whether I update like the above `python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip` or `pip3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` or `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` it will always keep complaining with the note above.

Comment: What is the output of `which python3.11`? Seems that `python3.11` you used to update pip is not the same `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11` that's raising the warning message.

Comment: Thank you @GinoMempin ! it is indeed different `which python3.11` shows `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11` - how can I change it? (I am wondering what caused it as it used to work before)

Comment: `opt/homebrew/opt/python3.11` however is an alias for `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.1`

Answer (score 1):

The Python interpreter that runs when you type `python` in your shell is determined by your PATH - unless you use the `alias` command, see note at bottom about why I suggest you do not use that.

Paths with the word *"local"* or *"homebrew"* in them are generally items installed by **homebrew**.

Paths starting with `/Library` or containing `Frameworks` are generally items supplied by Apple and should not be removed.

You appear to be running an Apple-supplied Python, so your PATH is wrong. If you want to run the **homebrew** Python, you need to run:

```
brew info Python
```

and read and do exactly what it says in respect of versioned links, unversioned links and your PATH.

---

Note that Python and pip versions are inextricably linked. You must run the pip that matches your Python or you will go around in circles updating the wrong one.

---

You can see which Python you'll run when entering `python` in your shell by running:

```
type python
```

Likewise, you can see which `pip` you'll start by running:

```
type pip
```

---

You can see which Python you are running from inside a script or inside an IDE, and also where it is looking for packages:

```
import sys
# Where is the Python I am running?
print(sys.executable)
# Where is it looking for packages?
print(sys.path)

# Where did it find Numpy, or any other package?
import numpy as np
print(np.__file__)
```

---

You can see where `pip` installed a package, say `flask` with:

```
pip show flask
```

---

**Note**: It is possible to define an *"alias"* like this:

```
alias python=/some/path/to/some/python
```

IMHO, that is a **bad** idea as aliases are not respected in:

- cron jobs, so you'll get problems as soon as you try to run a Python process on a schedule
- Python subprocesses, so you'll get problems as soon as you call `suborocess.run(...)`
- IDEs, so you'll get problems when you use PyCharm, VS Code and so on.

Also, if you alias `python` to some version 3.10 but don't alias `pip` to the same version, you will get in a mess.

**Note**: **homebrew** installs its packages in its *"Cellar"* and then makes symbolic links (symlinks) to them from `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/homebrew/bin`. In general, you should use the latter rather than directly using the binaries in the Cellar because then:

- **homebrew** can manage the links to allow you to switch versions simply
- you'll only need one PATH to allow you to use all **homebrew** packages

Comment: Thank you! I have done as you said, but the thing is, when I check where something is installed, like the package twarc-csv, it will show it, but say it doesn't find it (and i cannot uninstall it either): `~ %  pip3 show twarc-csv
Name: twarc-csv
Version: 0.7.1
Summary: A twarc plugin to output Twitter data as CSV
Home-page: https://github.com/docnow/twarc-csv
Author: Igor Brigadir
Author-email: igor.brigadir@gmail.com
License: 
Location: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: more-itertools, pandas, tqdm, twarc
Required-by: 
 ~ % which twarc-csv
twarc-csv not found`

Comment: I don't know `twarc-csv` but it may not provide a command-line tool called `twarc-csv` if it's just a Python package. In which case `type twarc-csv` will not find it because it is not an executable program that the shell can run, it's just a Python package that you can call from Python. If it does provide a command-line executable that you can run outside of Pyython, you'll need to find it with `find /opt -name twarc-csv -type f` then add the directory that contains it to your PATH.

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you! I know where the package is located, unfortunately it doesn't work though. (the pip version also won't be upgraded even if i stick to everything precisely as stated - I also tried to install pyenv now and it gives me the same pip message and twarc csv error too) https://global.discourse-cdn.com/twitter/original/3X/5/c/5cd581db4228b7858ec974abc9d91d4225091b16.png

Comment: even if i run pip3 which is 3.11 it will still look for the old 3.10 path when I try to install it seems: e.g. `WARNING: Target directory /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dataclasses_json-0.5.7.dist-info already exists` even when I delete the path, it will still create files there again apparently.